# Trying to copy cell value to different column(s) dependent on variable value

Tags: google-apps-script

i'm trying to transpose an array to a column dependent on a variable value.

Essentially what i'm trying to do is build a script which will transpose an input sheet, and depending on the language used in the specific input sheet row, transpose that rows values to a different column on an output.

i.e. depending on column value (C), values in columns A,B transpose to Column I,J,K depending on column value C.

Google sheets link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wuBfK4PKg79vCGGhsBPmHPT7hjfYNdR0srvX9nj0Ajs/edit?usp=sharing

I've already found a simple copyto script which works if it's one array with same language, but I need it to offset based on language.

Any help will be appreciated.

example code:

```
//missing the offset

function transpose() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("A2:C").copyTo(sheet.getRange("F2"), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);
}
```

Comment: Your script just copies the range `A2:C4` to `F2:H4`. Can you provide an example of what the output would actually look like? Have you used Apps Script or JavaScript before? Do you know how to use conditional statements?

Comment: Correct this script just transposes A2:C4 - i've added an example in column O of the spreadsheet.

I've worked with Apps Script before but i'm striking out on this one.

I know this could be done with conditional statements, but if the input grows to 50 languages it's hardly scaleable - instead i'd like to for example reference a language list, which maps to certain columns, and offset based on that reference.

Comment: For however many languages you have, will you always have a complete set? By a "set" I mean having input 1, 2 and 3. That is, if you have 10 languages, will you have 2 x input 1, 2 x input 2, 2 x input 3 for each language? Or is it possible that ENG has 2 sets of inputs and X has only 1? Or is it possible for a language to have only an input 1 and not input 2 and 3? It might be helpful to have some context as to what task you are trying to accomplish and why you need it in this particular format. I think this question is more complicated than it seems and you might need to break it up a bit.

Comment: Good questions:
A set will always be complete, as in contain input 1,2,3 (no blanks), but it's possible that language EN has 10 entries whereas language X or Y has a different n amount of entries.

The context is as follows, I have a library where I store copy used for advertisements, and this copy needs to be transposed into a different format 'feed', simply using a transpose formula doesn't do the job as it won't recognize what language the input is, i've tried writing an arrayformula with an index match to offset the output which also hasn't worked, hence->looking for a script solution

Answer (score 1):

#### Proposed Script

```js
function createReport() {
  // Initilaize Sheets, Ranges, Values
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet1 = file.getSheetByName("Blad1");
  let range1 = sheet1.getDataRange();
  let values1 = range1.getValues();

  let sheet2 = file.getSheetByName("Blad2");
  let range2 = sheet2.getDataRange();
  let values2 = range2.getValues();

  // Deal with headers
  let langs = values2[0];
  values1.shift(); // to remove headers

  // Creating array of sub arrays with info to paste into report
  // In this format:
  // [[Column to paste in, Input 1, Input 2, Input 3]]
  let output = [];
  values1.forEach((row, i) => {
    let outputRow = [];
    let whichCol = langs.findIndex((i) => i == row[3]) + 1;
    outputRow.push(whichCol);
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      outputRow.push(row[i]);
    }
    output.push(outputRow);
  });

  // With output array, pasting into report
  output.forEach((entry) => {
    let col = entry.shift();
    // Find where the next free slot is in column
    let occupiedRange = sheet2
      .getRange(1, col)
      .getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS)
    let height = occupiedRange.getHeight();

    // Transposing array
    set = entry.map((val) => [val]);

    // Inserting Values to Report
    let outRange = sheet2.getRange(height + 1, col, 3, 1);
    outRange.setValues(set);
  });
}
```

Source Data in `Blad1`

[image]

Destination Template and script in action in `Blad2`

[image]

#### Explanation

You'll notice its quite a bit longer than your script! What you are trying to do is deceptively complex, which is why I hesitated to answer fully as this script is so far removed from what you initially posted that it almost seemed like it was a "give me the code" question. Though you are new on the site and I had already written out most of the code, so what the hell. In future please try to include more info in your original question, your attempts and research. I have tried to keep it an concise as possible, but there may be certain syntax that you haven't come across, like `forEach` and `map`.

- The script first gets the data with `getValues` that returns 2D arrays of the values.
- I take out the headers on the source data, and use the headers on the target data to find the column index where the source data will end up. So `ENG` is index 1, and `X` index 2 etc.
- For each row in the source data it transforms it into an intermediary array (which is not necessary, but I think its clearer to understand each step). The intermediary array is composed of sub arrays representing each "set". Each sub array has this format `[Column_Index, Input1, Input2, Input3]`.
- Once this has been build, each of those sub arrays can be gone through to insert them into the output sheet, which I have called the "Report".
- Within this process is the need to get the first unoccupied row of the target column. So if `ENG` already has 3 sets that have been filled in, the script needs to know where the next set starts. It does this by using `getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS)` then `getHeight() + 1` to find the starting row for the set to be inserted.
- Also within this final process is the need to transform the array from this format:

  ```
  [1,2,3]
  ```

  Which Apps Script understands as a row, to a column, which would be this:

  ```
  [[1],[2],[3]]
  ```

  which was done with `map`.

I encourage you to use `Logger.log` to log a bunch of the values and inspect the output so that you can understand the script and adapt it to your needs. I have tried to name everything in a "friendly" manner.

#### References

- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Range object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Hi iansedano - I will have a look at the code and process today, thanks for the thorough explanation!

Comment: Reading over my answer I have just realised I didn't mention that the "report" is on a separate sheet `Blad2`, not on the same sheet as your example. Since using `getDataRange` it dynamically detects all the data on a sheet, so it will only work if you have _only_ source data on `Blad1` and _only_ the report columns and row labels ("Input 1,Input 2 etc") on `Blad2` - though of course you can adapt if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function Sort()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Blad1")
  var input = sh.getRange(1, 1, 4, 4).getValues();
  var output = sh.getRange("H1:K1").getValues();
  var index = [0]; var nInput = []
  for(var j = 1; j < output[0].length; j++)
  {
    for(var i = 1; i < input.length; i++) 
    if(output[0][j] == input[i][3]) index.push(i)
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) nInput.push(input[index[i]])
  var nData = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < nInput.length; i++)
  {
    for(var j = 0; j < nInput[0].length-1; j++)
    {
      if(nData[j] == null) nData[j] = []
      nData[j].push(nInput[i][j])
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(2, 9, nData.length, nData[0].length).setValues(nData); 
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code - whilst it does transpose correctly similar to the code in the description i'm missing the lookup function for the language (column) D -> i'm trying to map Col(D) to Row 1 in column I,J,K - and update based on the language provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function Sort()
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Blad1")
  var input = sh.getRange(1, 1, 7, 4).getValues();
  var output = sh.getRange("H1:K1").getValues();
  var index = [0]; var nInput = []
  for(var j = 1; j < output[0].length; j++)
  {
    nInput[j-1] = []
    for(var i = 1; i < input.length; i++)
    if(output[0][j] == input[i][3]) 
      for(var k = 0; k < input[0].length-1; k++) nInput[j-1].push(input[i][k])
  }
  var nData = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < nInput.length; i++)
  {
    for(var j = 0; j < nInput[0].length; j++)
    {
      if(nData[j] == null) nData[j] = []
      if(nInput[i][j]) nData[j].push(nInput[i][j])
      else nData[j].push("")
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(2, 9, nData.length, nData[0].length).setValues(nData)
}
```

This code will work only if you have same number of inputs (3 in this case) for each language.